# can I ask philosophy qustions on meta that the mods won't allow on the actual board

Tags: discussion

Can I ask philosophy questions on meta that the mods won't allow on the actual board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This would be discouraged by virtue of the structure/format of the sites.**

The meta sites in the StackExchange network are associated 'child' sites intended to handle discussion *about the parent site* with which they are associated. They are not intended to handle dubiously-topical overflow from the mainpage.

However, that *is* basically what the "third space", or chat areas, are intended for. Optimally they are even focal points to help develop perspective and refine problem formulations.

In my vision of a really successful Philosophy.SE I see serious, focused research-oriented activity taking place in the chat; the [Symposium](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/the-symposium) as an engine, driving quality content to the mainpage. At the very least it could be used to host discussion about events (theme weeks, contests...)